# Custom listview crashes in custom alertdialog

Tags: android, android-listview, android-alertdialog

what's my problem?
I'm trying to create a custom adapter in the dialogue. I can not understand what is the cause of the error.

**create dialog:**

```
  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    adb.setTitle("Choose contact");

    view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    adb.setView(view);

    deditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.deditText);
    deditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    dlvNames = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dlvCheck);

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER },
            null, null, null);

      startManagingCursor(cursor);


     while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
         ID=i;
         CID=Long.valueOf(cursor.getString(0));
         NAME=cursor.getString(1);
         PHONE=cursor.getString(2);

         Contact_List.add(new Contact(ID,CID,NAME,PHONE));

      i++;
     }

    contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this,Contact_List );
    //crashes here
    dlvNames.setAdapter(contactAdapter);

    dialog = adb.create();
    return dialog;
}
```

**create custom adapter:**

```
    public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

private final Activity context;
ArrayList<Contact> Contact_List;
LayoutInflater lInflater;


static class ViewHolder {
      public TextView tvName;
      public TextView tvPhone;

    }
public ContactAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Contact> Contact_List) {

    super(context, R.layout.item, Contact_List);
    this.context = context;
    this.Contact_List = Contact_List;
}

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

      //view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null, true);

      holder = new ViewHolder();
      holder.tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
      holder.tvPhone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);
      convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    Contact c = getContact(position);

    holder.tvName.setText(c.name);
    holder.tvPhone.setText(c.phone);


    return view;
}
  Contact getContact(int position) {
        return ((Contact) getItem(position));
      }
}
```

**LogCat:**

```
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263): java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at com.example.testreadcontacts.ContactAdapter.getView(ContactAdapter.java:50)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2271)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1102)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    01-17 06:40:31.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is ContactAdapter.java:50?

Comment: I meant what's on line 50 of that file?

Comment: I think the error in inflater or in nesting levels..

Comment: What's on line 50 of ContactAdapter.java?

Comment: convertView.setTag(holder);

Comment: In that case, Gabe's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  convertView.setTag(holder);
```

This is inside the block that checks for null.  If you hit this line, that variable is garunteed to be null.  You want it to be view.setTag instead.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the contact may be null, try:

```
Contact c = getContact(position);
if(c != null) {
   holder.tvName.setText(c.name);
   holder.tvPhone.setText(c.phone);
}
```